# how to install tftp-server on RHEL6

Tags: rpm, rhel6

I'm running on RHEL 6 and I'm getting this error when I run these codes:

````
    ```
[root@Server1 Packages]#yum -y install tftp-sever
    Error Downloading Packages:
      tftp-server-0.49-5.1.el6.i686: failure: Packages/tftp-server-0.49-5.1.el6.i686.rpm from InstallMedia: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

    ```
````

any help?

Comment: maybe ask it on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Start by cleaning YUM's cache with:

```
# yum clean all
```

Then, check that you have a repo that includes the `tftp-server` package with:

```
$ yum info tftp-server
```

The output should be similar to:

```
Name        : tftp-server
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 0.49
Release     : 8.el6
Size        : 57 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : The server for the Trivial File Transfer Protocol (TFTP)
URL         : http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/network/tftp/
License     : BSD
Description : The Trivial File Transfer Protocol (TFTP) is normally used only for
            : booting diskless workstations.  The tftp-server package provides the
            : server for TFTP, which allows users to transfer files to and from a
            : remote machine. TFTP provides very little security, and should not be
            : enabled unless it is expressly needed.  The TFTP server is run from
            : /etc/xinetd.d/tftp, and is disabled by default.
```

Note that this package should be included in the `base` repo:

> From repo   : base

However, from your output, in seems as though YUM tries to fetch it from a repo called `InstallMedia`. Verify that you have no broken repos enabled under /etc/yum.repos.d/*repo then try to install again.